# R - how to retrieve records with multiple column matching condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Input :

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5  
1  2  3  4  4  
2  3  4  5  6   
1  4  3  5  7  
3  4  5  6  7
```

Desired Output : Matching column condition used V1 and V3

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5  
1  2  3  4  4  
1  4  3  5  7
```

Code used : df[(df$V1 > 1 & df$V2 > 1) ,]

Above used code works well with small data where giving incorrect output with large data.

Please Advice.

Comment: How does it give an incorrect answer in large datasets? How is it wrong?

Comment: any other approach apart from this I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` to accomplish the same goal:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(V1 > 1 & V2 > 1)
```

But without more info on what's going wrong, this might not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find all rows, which have the same pair of entries in the first and third column?

This you can achieve with:

```
someLines <- df[which(duplicated(df[, c(1,3)]) | duplicated(df[, c(1,3)], fromLast = TRUE)),]
```

or, if you want only the indices:

```
which(duplicated(df[, c(1,3)]) | duplicated(df[, c(1,3)], fromLast = TRUE))
```